# Decomposition of the Riemann curvature operator in $4$ dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, curvature

Let $(M,g)$ be a $4$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. The Riemann curvature tensor can be viewed as an operator $\mathcal{R}:\Lambda^2(T^{\star}M)\longrightarrow \Lambda^2(T^{\star}M)$ defined in this way (I'm using Einstein's notation):

$$(\mathcal{R}(\omega))_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}R_{klij}\omega_{kl}$$

where $\omega_{ij}$ are the components of the $2$-form $\omega$ with respect to an orthonormal basis $\{e^i \wedge e^j\}_{i,j=1,..,4}$ and $R_{ijkt}$ are the components of the Riemann curvature tensor.

Because of the splitting $\Lambda^2 (T^{\star}M)=\Lambda_{+}\oplus \Lambda_{-}$, the operator $\mathcal{R}$ can be written in a block form

$$\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ ^{t}B & C \end{pmatrix}$$

where $^{t}A=A$, $^{t}C=C$ and $trA=trC=\frac{S}{4}$, with $S$ the scalar curvature of $M$.

So basically, if we write a $2$-form $\omega=\omega_{+} + \omega_{-}$ according to the splitting, we have that we can also write $\mathcal{R}\omega=(\mathcal{R}\omega)_{+}+(\mathcal{R}\omega)_{-}$: in particular, $\mathcal{R}(\omega_{\pm})=\mathcal{R}(\omega_{\pm})_{+}+\mathcal{R}(\omega_{\pm})_{-}$ and, for example, $A$ "sends" $\omega_+$ in $\mathcal{R}(\omega_{+})_{+}$.

Now, I read in a few papers that, if we call $A_{ij}$ the components of the matrix $A$, with $i,j=1,2,3$, we have that $A_{12}=A_{13}=0$ if and only if $A$ is a multiple of the identity matrix. How is that possible?

I tried to work directly with the components of the Weyl tensor $W$ of the manifold, since its self-dual part is strictly related to the matrix $A$, but I couldn't get anything. I tried also to exploit the fact that a matrix is a multiple of the identity matrix if and only if it commutes with any other matrix, but I don't know if it's useful.

EDIT: In these days I read also that this fact may be related to the property of the curvature form $\Omega$, i.e. $R_g ^{\star}\Omega = g^{-1}\Omega g$, where $R_g$ denotes the right multiplication by $g\in SO(4)$ in the bundle of orthonormal frames of $N$. How could it help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be over complicating things, just quickly looking this is what I saw.

> Now, I read in a few papers that, if we call Aij the components of the matrix A, with i,j=1,2,3, we have that A12=A13=0 if and only if A is a multiple of the identity matrix. How is that possible?

The operator $\mathcal{R}$ can be written in a block form

$$\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ ^{t}B & C \end{pmatrix}$$

where $^{t}A=A$, $^{t}C=C$ and $trA=trC=\frac{S}{4}$, with $S$ the scalar curvature of $M$.

Since $^{t}A=A$, we know the $3\times 3$ matrix will be symmetric about it's diagonal. The reverse direction is easy to show, since if we assume the contrapositive, (i.e. $A$ is not a multiple of the identity matrix) then $A_{1,2}\neq A_{1,3}\neq 0$ follows naturally.

Now, assume $^{t}A=A$ and $A_{1,2}=A_{1,3}=0$. Write out $A$ with all of the zeros in place (all positions such that $i\neq j$). This could be a multiple of the identity matrix. What's left to show is the diagonals $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are in fact all equal. So use the fact that $trA = \frac{S}{4}$, which I'm assuming applies to each entry of the diagonal. Since $\frac{S}{4}$ is constant, then $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$, and can be written as some scaled version of the identity matrix.

**EDIT**

> Why must $A_{2,3} = 0$?

I didn't explicitly mention this, it was inherent to my line of reasoning above.

If $A_{2,3} \neq 0$ then the operator $\mathcal{R}$ has for matrix $A$ in block form a free variable when reduced to echelon form. If the free-variable is present, "$A$ sending $\omega_+$ in $\mathcal{R}(\omega_+)_+$" is not unique. I'm assuming the spectral properties of the operator are commutative, if not, the entire argument falls apart.

Comment: There's something that I still don't understand: if $A_{12}=A_{13}=0$, then $A$ is diagonal if and only if $A_{23}=0$, which I don't think is automatically obtained from the hypothesis

Comment: @Lukath, see the edit to the post.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying, but I don't know if it's correct: as far as I know, the only way you can "transform" the matrix $A$ is by orthogonal similarity, because it depends strictly on the orthonormal frame chosen and the changes of orthonormal frames are realized by multiplication for an orthogonal matrix. I remember that the reduction to the echelon form cannot be obtained by similarity.

Comment: @Lukath, I wasn't transforming $A$. I was pointing out that the Berger decomposition of the curvature operator $\mathcal{R}$ has $A$ equal to its diagonal, if it wasn't then there is a free variable (which you can see easily but putting $A$ in echelon form), and the free variable would ruin the decomposition. Assuming the Berger decomposition, your question was elementary linear algebra. I don't have my references in front of me, so this could not be the Berger decomposition, or you could be working with a non-commutative curvature operator. I assumed commutativity.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Looking at the proof of the Berger decomposition may help, search "curvature decompositions", "curvature decompositions on Einstein manifolds" etc.

Comment: Thank you, I saw some references about Berger decomposition, which I am a bit unfamiliar with, but it seems that it can be applied to Einstein manifolds only, because of the commutativity of $\mathcal{R}$ with the Hodge $\star$ operator. In my case, I have no such hypotheses on the manifold $M$: it would be Einstein if and only if $B=0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104833/discussion-between-lukath-and-lmidh).